# What does "a trap in itself" mean?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I came across this sentence: "People often think they need to find that one thing they're passionate about, but that framework is a trap in itself." ([source](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/passion-trap-michael-gervais/))

I'm wondering why it's not "a trap itself," but "a trap in itself." Could anybody tell me what it means and how I use it in the future.

Comment: Hello,  This seems to be a quote of Michael Gervais https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/passion-trap-michael-gervais/  When you are asking about a phrase that you have seen, please tell us the source, and if possible link to the source.

Comment: Yes, you're right in saying this is a quote of Michael Gervais. When I googled "a trap in itself," I just found out this exsample by chance, and thought, "Wow, someone really used it that way," but I was not sure what use it is. Hmm, again, I'm sorry for not attaching the link to the source.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the source to the question.  Why were you googling "a trap in itself"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lexico gives a definition](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/in_itself) of "in itself":

> Viewed in its essential qualities...

So this means that the essential properties of the framework (of seeking the thing you are passionate about) is a trap. Presumably he means that you will become trapped in the search, and not enjoy what you already have.  It is a stoical point of view.

Lexico gives the example (slightly simplified here):

> Bringing up a family is a full-time job in itself’

The phrase "in itself" adds very little to the meaning of the sentence.  It suggests that "bringing up a family" is a full-time job, and it can't be made less than a full-time job.

Comment: I didn’t get what “essential qualities” means here, but I think of “in [and of] itself” as meaning not due to causing or being caused by any other factor.